# Null received in Bundle while passing extra data from main activity to BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, android-pendingintent, android-broadcast

When I am sending the data from one activity it calls BroadcastReceiver, and  I am receiving  null in BroadcastReceiver.

**here is my code for the BroadcastReceiver**...

```
public class Notification_reciver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    NotificationManager nm;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                nm = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        CharSequence title = " birthday...";
        CharSequence message = " Today is your one Friends BirthDay";
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, MainScreenSlideActivity.class);
        resultIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
         Bundle b = intent.getExtras();
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, resultIntent, 0,b);

          String userName=b.getString("userName");
         Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), userName+" set in Notication reciver", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        Notification notif = new Notification.Builder(context).setContentTitle("Today is your one Friends BirthDay")
                .setContentText("Click to Birthday Wish").setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher).build();

        notif.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, contentIntent);

        // hide the notification after its selected
        notif.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;


        nm.notify(0, notif);
    }
```

and the activity from where I am sending the data is.

```
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Notification_reciver.class);
            Bundle c = new Bundle();
            c.putString("userName", "Sarbjot Singh");
            Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), c + " ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            intent.setAction("" + Math.random());
            intent.putExtras(c);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            // PendingIntent pendingIntent =
            // PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), 0, intent, 0);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), 0, intent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 00);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
            calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
                    pendingIntent);
new Utils().setPreference("isFirstStart", false, getActivity().getApplicationContext());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got my answer **here is my code..;**

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Notification_reciver.class);
Bundle c = new Bundle();
c.putString("userName", FirstName);
intent.setAction("" + Math.random());
intent.putExtras(c);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent,
                                                         PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 00);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
                          pendingIntent);
Utils.setPreference("isFirstStart", false,
                    FacebookBirthdaysActivity.this.getApplicationContext());
```

**the reciver is.**

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    nm = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, SplashAnimationActivity.class);
    resultIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    Bundle b = intent.getExtras();
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, resultIntent, 0, b);
    String userName = b.getString("userName");
    CharSequence title = " Birthday...";
    CharSequence message = " Today is "+userName+" BirthDay";
    Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), userName + " set in Notication reciver", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();
    Notification notif = new Notification.Builder(context).setContentTitle("Today is your one Friends BirthDay")
            .setContentText("Click to Birthday Wish").setSmallIcon(R.drawable.facebook).build();
    // @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    // Notification notif = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,
    // "Today is your one Friends BirthDay", System.currentTimeMillis());
    notif.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, contentIntent);

    // hide the notification after its selected
    notif.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    /*
     * Notification notif = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,
     * "Crazy About Android...", System.currentTimeMillis());
     * notif.setLatestEventInfo(context, from, message, contentIntent);
     */
    nm.notify(0, notif);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In sending class, use:

```
myIntent.putExtra(key, String); // Where key is the name of string which you will use to catch in other class and String is your data string.
```

In Receiving class use:

```
Intent myIntent = getIntent();
myIntent.getStringExtra(key);  //here key will the string that you set on sending class.
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this [Android Description](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtras(android.content.Intent)), you need:

> The keys must include a package prefix, for example the app com.android.contacts would use names like "com.android.contacts.ShowAll".

IMOP, it's much easier to just use `intent.putExtra(key,value)` and retrieve via `intent.getStringExtra(String key)`.

Comment: but there is no fun of that key...it suport as normal as is.  intent.putExtras(c);and on reciving side its is.Bundle b = intent.getExtras();and that verable geting is.String userName = b.getString("userName");

Comment: @Sarbjot_Singh did you try to add your package name as prefix of your key?